# Which Query is Optimized

Tags: mysql

I have employees table with 3 column id, name, salary, I have index to the salary column

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM employees WHERE salary IN (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM employees);

id  select_type   table        type    possible_keys  key     key_len  ref       rows  Extra                         
------  ------------  -----------  ------  -------------  ------  -------  ------  ------  ------------------------------
 1  PRIMARY       <subquery2>  system  (NULL)         (NULL)  (NULL)   (NULL)       1                                
 1  PRIMARY       employees    ALL     test           (NULL)  (NULL)   (NULL)       5  Using where                   
 2  MATERIALIZED  (NULL)       (NULL)  (NULL)         (NULL)  (NULL)   (NULL)  (NULL)  Select tables optimized away 



EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM employees  INNER JOIN (SELECT  MAX(salary) AS mx FROM employees) AS tbl ON tbl.mx=employees.salary;

id  select_type  table       type    possible_keys  key     key_len  ref       rows  Extra                         
------  -----------  ----------  ------  -------------  ------  -------  ------  ------  ------------------------------
 1  PRIMARY      <derived2>  system  (NULL)         (NULL)  (NULL)   (NULL)       1                                
 1  PRIMARY      employees   ALL     test           (NULL)  (NULL)   (NULL)       5  Using where                   
 2  DERIVED      (NULL)      (NULL)  (NULL)         (NULL)  (NULL)   (NULL)  (NULL)  Select tables optimized away
```

Which to use is it MATERIALIZED optmized or DERIVED,As MySQL needs the subquery result, it materializes that result into a temporary table.

And Derived Table is also a temporary table so which one is optimized ?? And Why ??

Thank you in Advance

Comment: why not just `SELECT * FROM employees WHERE salary = (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM employees);` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both will have the same performance. MySQL transforms the first query into the second.

`Select tables optimized away` means that MySQL can "take a shortcut" and not read an actual table (`SELECT MIN(indexed_field)`).

In this plan there is a full scan on `employees`, probably because it only has 5 rows. You should add some more rows (and different salaries) to see what will actually happen.